# Use gem axlsx Ruby on Rails exporting data via AJAX not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, rubygems, axlsx

I'm using the gem **gem 'axlsx_rails'** and I want to export data to an excel File but I need to send data to the controller via AJAX, like checkboxes clickd in js or items selected. The problem is that with ajax the data is sent to controller but the xlsx file is not downloading but using the rails *Link-to* function works good.

This is my function in *controller*. It sents a variable to the xlsx file that is rendering just the **name** attribute for **user**. Not big deal.

```
def export_xlsx_report_table
    enterprise = current_user.enterprise
    p "Params!!"
    p params
    @user = User.where(id: params[:user_id])
end
```

This is my ajax function. I changed the url removing the last **.xlsx** and still doesn't work

```
$.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "/export_xlsx_report_table.xlsx",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { user_id: 1 },
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
        }).done(function(data){

        });
```

This is the html file. When I click the **link_to** function works good but clicking the js function goes to the controller but nothing happens.

```
<%= link_to "Exportar reporte", export_xlsx_report_table_path(:user_id => 1, format: "xlsx"), class: 'btn btn-default btn-sm' %>

 <a onclick="report_sales.export_report()" class="btn blue"> EXPORTAR REPORTE</a>
```

Thank you for any help you can give me.

Comment: Write the code in your post instead of attaching the pictures.

Answer (score 0):

You can't download a file to disk from JS: it is a security concern.

Take a look at the blog post below for a good workaround - 
http://johnculviner.com/post/2012/03/22/Ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads-with-jQuery-File-Download.aspx